# When using setContentView, I see the system wallpaper for a second

Tags: android, android-view

I'm switching a `contentView` to fullscreen mode, and when the view is being switched, I'm able to see the system wallpaper for a couple sections, before the view is actually changed, and vice versa when going back to the `main` content view.

How can I get this to not happen, or at least how can I change the background to be black while it's being switched.

Sample code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.fullscreen);
```

I use this when setting the content view to fullscreen, which is where the problem shows up.

*** EDIT ***

At the very first of the application, I set the content to main:

```
super.onCreate(b);
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

And then on button click listener,  I am setting it to a different layout like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.fullscreen);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't why you are having this issue. By the way, if you're trying to get a full-screen activity you can try something like:

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

And use just an "ordinary" layout for your activity.

Comment: I added more detail to my question.  Also I am working with Android 3.x +